# Perko pair - What's the handedness of these pictures?

Tags: knot-theory

In 1974, a paper titled [On the Classification of Knots](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1974-045-02/S0002-9939-1974-0353294-X/S0002-9939-1974-0353294-X.pdf) by Ken Perko appeared showing that the knots $10_{161}$ and $10_{162}$ in Dale Rolfsen's knot table were actually the same knot. He included this picture, showing how to deform one into the other:

[image]

*Edit: [A clearer, color-coded version](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaaac/Perko-page.html)*

From that point on, $10_{161}$ and $10_{162}$ became known as the *Perko pair*, or the *Perko knot*.

Another view of the pair can be found [on the KnotPlot website](https://knotplot.com/perko/). That link shows its own explicit deformation between $10_{161}$ and $10_{162}$, and its pair looks like this:

[image]

Wikipedia also has pictures of the pair (click [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Ten_onehundredandsixtyone.gif/800px-Ten_onehundredandsixtyone.gif) or [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Ten_onehundredandsixtytwo.gif/800px-Ten_onehundredandsixtytwo.gif) for bigger images):

[image]

Here's a version that Perko himself drew (redrawn by me):

[image]

There's a problem, though. I mean, for one thing, these all kinda look nothing like each other. But a bigger problem is this: the Perko knot is *chiral*! That is, there's a left-handed and right-handed version.

I've drawn [my own projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q74d2.jpg) of the Perko knot:

[image]

and I'm fairly certain that the one that I drew matches the handedness found in the original paper, as well as the KnotPlot one. However, Wikipedia's first image (the one of $10_{161}$) seems to be a mirror version.

So, my question is this:

**Call the one that I drew the *left-handed Perko knot*, and its mirror image the *right-handed Perko knot*. What is the handedness of Wikipedia's second image? What are the handednesses of the ones that Perko drew? And am I right in saying that the paper's image and KnotPlot's image are both left-handed, and that Wikipedia's first image is right-handed?**

Comment: Incidentally, [MathWorld's images](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerkoPair.html) are _incorrect_! More details can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/9059/65995) and [here](https://richardelwes.co.uk/2013/08/14/the-revenge-of-the-perko-pair/), and [here](https://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/debunking-knot-theorys-favourite-urban-legend/).

Comment: The signature of either Perko knot is nonzero. So one could use that to distinguish between the right and left hand versions. Additionally, the Jones polynomial of either Perko knot is not symmetric under $t\mapsto t^{-1}$, and so it can be used to distinguish the right and left hand versions as well.

Comment: A Great Lakes sailor has told me that he'd probably describe it as a "double bowline-Ashley's" or maybe just a "double Ashley's".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagrams in *On the Classification of Knots* are **left-handed**.

The pictures from KnotPlot are **left-handed**.

Wikipedia's pictures are **right-handed**.

The first of Perko's drawings is **right-handed**; the second is **left-handed**.

I determined this experimentally by tying the knots in my headphones and manipulating them until I got them into a form I recognized. I didn't compute the Jones polynomials, since that would probably take around an hour per knot.

This was much harder than I thought it would be. I thought that a physical knot would naturally end up in the configuration of "lowest energy" (whatever that means) when the ends are pulled, but it turns out that knots are much more annoying than that.

I have a lot of respect for the early knot theorists who made knot tables before anyone knew how to rigorously prove that any two knots were distinct. And I don't blame them for thinking the Perko pair was two distinct knots.

Here's the (left-handed) Perko knot tied in my headphones: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMFvE.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The sign of the writhe of any 10-crossing diagram (the sum of the signs of the crossings, which must be either + or - 10 or 8 for the Perko pair knot) will show the handedness of any particular drawing. It's no big deal.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of checking the writhe… though, to be fair, it doesn't _prove_ which handedness it must be unless we already knew the possible writhes of a minimal diagram of a given handedness of the knot. In any case: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question, though, Perko!

Comment: I'll put a link to your Quora response, in case anyone who sees this in the future finds it interesting: https://www.quora.com/How-often-are-new-knots-invented/answer/Ken-Perko/comment/81352245

Comment: Actually, the numerical value of the minimal crossing writhe doesn't really matter from the standpoint of handedness; just whether it's + or -. ("in case"? Shame on those who don't!)

Answer (score 2):

I like this new diagram of the Perko pair knot; it's in "twisted ribbon" form, which I have not seen before. --Ken Perko